# Sort dictionary python by value (word2vec)

Tags: python, sorting, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I want to sort my `dict` by value, but if I apply this code it doesn't work (it print only my `key-value` pairs without any kind of sorting). If I change `key=lambda x: x[1] to x[0]` it correctly sort by `key`, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

e_science = Word2Vec.load("clean_corpus_science.model")
e_pokemon = Word2Vec.load("clean_corpus_pokemon.model")

science_vocab = list(e_science.wv.vocab)
pokemon_vocab = list(e_pokemon.wv.vocab)

vocab_intersection = list(set(science_vocab).intersection(set(pokemon_vocab)))

similarity = []
for i in range(0, len(vocab_intersection)):
  similarity.append(1-cosine(e_science[vocab_intersection[i]], e_pokemon[vocab_intersection[i]]))

hashmap = {}
for i in range(0, len(similarity)):
  hashmap[vocab_intersection[i]] = {similarity[i]} 

dict(sorted(hashmap.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: What python version are you in? In older ones dictionaries are unordered

Comment: 3.6.9, I'm using colab notebook

Comment: sorting with `lambda x: x[0]` sorts by key, using `lambda x: x[1]` sorts by value

Comment: I've already tried, but x[1] doesn't work (instead x[0] correctly sort by key)

Comment: could you share one of the values in your hashmap?

Comment: {'alleviate': {0.6330273151397705}, 'foreword': {0.45868542790412903}, 'thingsnn1': {0.6718924045562744}, 'resized': {0.3699944019317627}, 'orbs': {0.30699896812438965}, ..... if I sort by key, it do it. But by value it prints in the same order if I don't sort anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to sort sets, and Python isn't sure how to order them. Take your scores out of the sets, and then you can sort as expected.

```
dict(sorted(hashmap.items(), key=lambda x: tuple(x[1])[0]))
```

That's pretty ugly though, you may want to do the cleanup in a separate step.